# How to Use SSLContext with Python Requests Library?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

The `certifi` library often runs into issues with domain certificates, but in the standard `urllib.request` library has no issue.

If I set the context to use the certifi's file, I get the SSL error,

```py
import ssl
import certifi
import requests.urllib as urlrq

resp = urlrq.urlopen(url="https://<web address>/rest/info?f=json", 
                                  context=ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where()))
```

if I use the standard library and set the context as follows:

```py
import ssl
import certifi
import requests.urllib as urlrq

resp = urlrq.urlopen(url="https://<web address>/rest/info?f=json", 
                                  context=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1))
```

No SSL error.

How can I get requests to honor this `SSLContext`?

Answer (score 1):

Creating an `ssl.SSLContext()` on its own doesn't enable certificate verification or load CA certificates by default. This is why you're not seeing SSL errors. Using `ssl.create_ssl_context()` does set verification by default.

So the issue here isn't with `SSLContext` or `certifi`, it's with the website's certificate and how you're constructing your `SSLContext`. Next step would be to look into why the certificate the website is presenting isn't valid.

Comment: is there a way to garnish more information from urllib3/requests on what is the cause of the error?

Comment: Exact error message from requests: (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),